# retrieving float values using sqlite3_column_double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm relatively new to iPhone programming so I apologize if this seems a simple question. I have latitude/location columns in my table (FLOAT type) that I am trying to retrieve from my SQLite database.

I can retrieve my character/text based db columns, but don't know how to retrieve my float values. Should I be formatting the attributes using NSString or something else? I wish to use the float values further downstream with CLLocationDistance.

```
// the array of locations that we will create
NSMutableArray *locations = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

const char *sql = "SELECT locations.name, \
locations.address, \
locations.city, \
locations.state, \
locations.phone, \
locations.zip, \
locations.latitude, \
locations.longitude \
FROM locations \
WHERE category = ?1";

// the sqlite statement object that will hold our result set 
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

// prepare the statement to compile the SQL query into byte-code
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

// reset query before execution
sqlite3_reset(statement);

// set bind variable
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [categoryParameter UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK) {
    // step through the results - once for each row
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        // allocate a location object to add to the pharmacies array
        Location *location = [[Location alloc] init];

        // the second parameter is the column index (0 based) in
        // the result set
        char *name = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        char *address = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *city = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *state = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        char *phone = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        char *zipcode = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
        float latitude = (float) sqlite3_column_double(statement, 6);
        float longitude = (float) sqlite3_column_double(statement, 7);

        // set all attributes of the location
        location.name = (name) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name] : @"";
        location.address = (address) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:address] : @"";
        location.city = (city) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:city] : @"";
        location.state = (state) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:state] : @"";
        location.phone = (phone) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:phone] : @"";
        location.zipcode = (zipcode) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:zipcode] : @"";

        [locations addObject:location];
        [location release];
    }

    // finalize the statement to release its resources
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the latitude and longitude stored as degrees in the table?  Does your Location object have a CLLocationCoordinate2D property called, say, coordinates to put the coordinates in?

If yes, just set the values directly because CLLocationDegrees is actually just a double.  For example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
coords.latitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 6);
coords.longitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 7);

location.coordinates = coords;
```

Comment: I'm storing coordinates e.g. 40.759011 and 73.9844722

Comment: Right, that's the same as CLLocationDegrees.  Do you have fields in the Location object to store the coordinates in?

Comment: Sorry, bit confused. In my location object (location.h and .m) I have defined float latitude; and float longitude;

Comment: Ok, so just do `location.latitude = sqlite3...` and `location.longitude = sqlite3...`.  However, I recommend you change them from float to CLLocationDegrees in the Location object to avoid loss of precision.

Comment: Weird. I thought I had tried that before. Looks like it is working now. Thanks for the CLLocationDegrees advice. Float rounds up and puts a sample location at least 0.5 miles from where it should be.