# Populating a C struct

Tags: c, sqlite

I would like to assign value fetched from sqlite database to a c-struct so I do that as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t    shortID;
    double       temp;
    unsigned long timestamp;
} location_t;

static uint8_t prv_set_value(lwm2m_data_t* dataP,
                           location_t* tempData)
{
    uint8_t ret = COAP_205_CONTENT;
    sqlite3 *db;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;

    // connect to sqlite
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.sqlite3", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connection to SQLITE established!.\n" );
    }
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT temp FROM envirment ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1", -1, &res, 0);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fetch data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        return 1;
    }
    rc = sqlite3_step(res);
    if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Temperature value ==== : %s\n", sqlite3_column_double(res, 0));

         tempData->temp = sqlite3_column_double(res, 0);
        fprintf(stdout, "Temp value from temperature_data_t: %s\n", tempData->temp);

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);

         }
    return ret;
}
```

Data is fetched from the sqlite database. I'm doing a check to see if the function behaves as intended so I display the value before and after the assignment. The output from the struct assignment `tempData->temp = sqlite3_column_double(res, 0);`as displayed in next line `fprintf(stdout, " Temp value from temperature_data_t: %s\n", tempData->temp);` is `null`. Following is the function output:

```
Connection to SQLITE established!.
Temperature value ==== : 29.1
Temp value from temperature_data_t:  (null)
```

What is the correct way to assign fetched to `tempData->temp`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempData->temp = sqlite3_column_double(res, 0);` is correct but because *tempData->temp* is a double, not a `char*`, replace

```
fprintf(stdout, "Temp value from temperature_data_t: %s\n", tempData->temp) ;
```

by

```
fprintf(stdout, "Temp value from temperature_data_t: %f\n", tempData->temp);
```

---

I suppose the line

```
fprintf(stdout, "Temperature value ==== : %s\n", sqlite3_column_double(res, 0));
```

is in fact

```
fprintf(stdout, "Temperature value ==== : %s\n", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
```

because `sqlite3_column_double` doesn't return a `char*`

---

May be see also : [retrieving float values using sqlite3_column_double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437876/retrieving-float-values-using-sqlite3-column-double)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works. How do I access `tempData->temp` from a function in different file. I mean the above function is from an object `temperature.c` initialised from a file `myobjects.c` that contains the `main()`function. Now want to access `tempData->temp`from within `myobject.c`

Comment: @arilwan move the definition of `location_t` in a header file (extension 'h') and _#include_ that file when needed like _myobjects.c_ and _myobject.c_ in your case, that allows them to know the type and use it, so to receive _tempData_ in argument of a function

Comment: I can see what you mean now.

Comment: @arilwan ok, fine